# Cut out part of an image

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to cut out a Part of an image.
My plan was to create a layer with a Image, but the image overflows the layer.

It should look like this example:

[image: the cutted image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
using (CGLayer starLayer = CGLayer.Create (g, rect.Size)) {
            // set fill to blue
            starLayer.Context.SetFillColor (0f, 0f, 1f, 0.4f);
            starLayer.Context.AddLines (myStarPoints);

            starLayer.Context.AddQuadCurveToPoint(this.points [3].X, this.points [3].Y, this.points [2].X, this.points [2].Y);
            starLayer.Context.AddQuadCurveToPoint(this.points [5].X, this.points [5].Y, this.points [4].X, this.points [4].Y);
            starLayer.Context.FillPath ();



            double width =  Math.Abs((double)(this.points [1].X - this.points [0].X));
            float prop = this.tmpimage.Size.Width / (float)width;

            float height = (this.tmpimage.Size.Height / prop);

            double centerteeth = (Math.Sqrt (Math.Pow ((this.points [4].X - this.points [2].X), 2.0) + Math.Pow ((this.points [4].Y - this.points [2].Y), 2.0))) / 2 - (width/2);



            starLayer.Context.DrawImage (new RectangleF ((float)centerteeth + this.points[2].X, this.points [2].Y, (float)width, height), this.imagerotated.CGImage);


            // draw the layer onto our screen
            float starYPos = 5;
            float starXPos = 5;


            g.DrawLayer (starLayer, new PointF (starXPos, starYPos));



        }
```

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish? My thought is to use a `UIImageView` with the `ContentMode` set to center, but I'm not visualization what you want the end product to look like.

Comment: I don't find the time to give you a detailed example but you should have a look at `CAShapeLayer`. You create a path (your mask) then assign it to the CAShapeLayer and use your UIView's layer property's SetMask() method to set the shape layer as the mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found a solution that worked for me, thank you for help anyway.

The imagesublayer is movable in the mainlayer.

Thats my solution:

```
        CALayer imageLayer = new CALayer (Layer);
        imageLayer.Frame = Layer.Bounds;
        imageLayer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;


        CAShapeLayer maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
        maskLayer.FillRule = CAShapeLayer.FillRuleEvenOdd;
        maskLayer.Frame = Frame;


        double width =  Math.Abs((double)(this.points [1].X - this.points [0].X));
        float prop = this.tmpimage.Size.Width / (float)width;
        float height = (this.tmpimage.Size.Height / prop);


        CALayer lay = new CALayer ();
        lay.Bounds = new RectangleF (0, 0, (float)width, height);
        lay.Position = this.points[6];

        lay.Contents = this.tmpimage.CGImage;
        layers [6] = lay;

        imageLayer.AddSublayer (lay);



        CGPath p1 = new CGPath();

        p1.MoveToPoint (this.points [2]);
        p1.AddQuadCurveToPoint(this.points [3].X, this.points [3].Y, this.points [4].X, this.points [4].Y);
        p1.AddQuadCurveToPoint(this.points [5].X, this.points [5].Y, this.points [2].X, this.points [2].Y);

        maskLayer.Path = p1;

        imageLayer.Mask = maskLayer;
        Layer.AddSublayer (imageLayer);


        CAShapeLayer pathLayer1 = new CAShapeLayer ();
        pathLayer1.Path = maskLayer.Path;
        pathLayer1.LineWidth = 0f;
        pathLayer1.StrokeColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
        pathLayer1.FillColor = UIColor.Clear.CGColor;
        Layer.AddSublayer (pathLayer1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a quick solution to get it done, can you use two images to accomplish what you need? (A black image, then the background) Put one `UIImageView` on top of another?

I usually only drop into using `CoreGraphics` for two reasons:

- There is no other way to accomplish my goal
- Using plain `UIViews` are not performant enough

Comment: The problem is, that I need to move the image under the mask like moving a paper under a loupe. And the second thing is, that the shape/mask must be editable from the user.

Comment: Sounds like you are going to have to use `CoreGraphics` then. Mainly for the magnification part. I think you could still use an image view for the overlay by using pieces of images the user could drag around.